# Pass JavaScript Function in href

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am working on VS2103 Cordova App. I have created list of items. I want to pass data to another page when i press on item. I've created this list by jQuery.

Here is my code :

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if ((Provider == "Doctors")) {
        $("#list").append('<li class="list-message" ><a class="w-clearfix w-inline-block" href="javascript:ProviderDetails(' + data[i].DoctorName + ',' + data[i].DoctorAddress + ',' + data[i].DoctorPhone + ',' + data[i].DoctorPhone2 + ',' + data[i].DoctorPhone3 + ',' + data[i].DocLat + ',' + data[i].DocLong + ',' + data[i].DoctorNotes + ',' + data[i].Category + ');" data-load="1"><div class="w-clearfix column-left"><div class="image-message"><img src="images/Doctors.png"></div></div><div class="column-right"><div class="message-title">' + data[i].DoctorName + '</div><div class="message-text">' + data[i].DoctorAddress + '</div></div></a></li>');
    }
}
```

And here is my function :

```
 function ProviderDetails(Name, Address, Tel, Phone2, Phone3, Lat, Lang, Notes, Category) {
          localStorage.setItem("Name", Name);
          localStorage.setItem("Address", Address);
          localStorage.setItem("Tel", Tel);
          localStorage.setItem("Phone2", Phone2);
          localStorage.setItem("Phone3", Phone3);
          localStorage.setItem("Lat", Lat);
          localStorage.setItem("Lang", Lang);
          localStorage.setItem("Notes", Notes);
          localStorage.setItem("Category", Category);
          window.location.href = "../Details.html";
      }
```

It doesn't do any thing when i press any items . Any help ?

Comment: You must be getting error in the browser console.

Comment: No i get correct data but I seems It dosen't enter the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention on how you build the string:

href="javascript:ProviderDetails(' + data[i].DoctorName + ',' ......

you need to add the string delimiters:

href="javascript:ProviderDetails(\'' + "data[i].DoctorName" + '\',\'' .....

Your function is declared as:

```
function ProviderDetails(Name, Address, Tel, Phone2, Phone3, Lat, Lang, Notes, Category)
{
....
}
```

Now, because your function expects strings as input you can call your function as:

ProviderDetails('string1', 'string2', .....)

Your javascript loop instead produces:

ProviderDetails(string1, string2, .....)

For javascript now the parameters are considered as variables, i.e.,  string1 is no more a string but a value contained in the variable string1.
But because you do not have such a variable your function call does not work.

So, the delimiters are important to instruct js to understand the beginning and end of a string.

As a delimiter you can you the symbols: ' or ".

But you need to escape the delimiter itself if you want to use it inside the strings:

var a = 'this isn't a string';  // wrong  because the inner delimiter is not escaped.

var a = 'this isn\'t a string';  // OK because the inner delimiter is escaped

Of course if you use inside the string the other delimiter you do not need to escape it.

var a = "this isn't a string";    // this is OK

Comment: yes its running . please explain what is string delimiters and when should i use it . thank you

Comment: @prime I updated the answer. Let me know if now it's ok